# How do I choose which version of the IC MT8870 should I use?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, cellphone

I am following [this guide](http://www.worldofmcu.com/2012/12/dual-tone-multiple-frequency-DTMF.html) to hooking up a phone to a circuit, depending on the DTMF tones. However, when I went to buy one, I realized there were lots of different "editions"/models.

**Which one should I choose? Does it really matter in my case?** To make this question more useful for future visitors, how did you get your answer?

[Datasheet for MT8870](http://www.natalnet.br/~aroca/afron/mt8870.pdf)

Comment: This isn't your traditional "shopping" question, but rather covers a point at which selection becomes a puzzle for many less experienced designers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first page of the datasheet explains the suffix codes except for the "-1".

- E is 18-pin [PDIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package)
- S is 18-pin [SOIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_integrated_circuit)
- N is 20-pin [SSOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-outline_integrated_circuit#SOP)
- R is tape/reel, for [P+P equipment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMT_placement_equipment), otherwise it comes in tubes

Obviously if you want through-hole you pick some sort of DIP.

The "-1" suffix is explained under "Applications" as being appropriate for CEPT signaling rather than BT.

Comment: I would want to use MT8870DE for the 18 pin version that I can breadboard with?